# Use Radio button to direct resource exit route by user preference

Tags: anylogic

Use radio button as interface to be used by user to direct resource exit route.

[image]

The radio button options will be linked to one of the routs or both of them.

[image]

I have used the function `radio.getValue();` for enter and enter1.

[image]

I would like manually choose resources enter route (enter, enter1 or enter and enter1) before running the model. My methods of introducing variable or parameters failed.

Not sure how to link the exit to the radio button?

Comment: sorry, can you edit and clarify, really not clear what you want to achieve. What should happen in each option? Your code is wrong in many ways, though ;)

Comment: Thanks Benjamin. Just edited the question. Hope it is clear now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code in the "on exit" code of your `exit` block:

```
if (radio.getValue() == 0) {
    enter.take(agent);
}
else if (radio.getValue() == 1) {
    enter1.take(agent);
}
else if (radio.getValue() == 2) {
    // decide yourself which enter block, can use randomTrue(.5)....
}
else {
    error("Unexpected radio choice");
}
```